# How to relate BCS's particle number uncertainty with the quotient between the gap and Fermi energy

Tags: superconductivity

I'm trying to prove that the uncertainty in the particle number of the BCS Theory is related to the quotient between the energy gap and Fermi energy:

$$\left \langle \left ( N - \overline{N} \right )^{2} \right \rangle \simeq N\frac{\Delta }{\varepsilon _{F}}\ll N$$

I'm using Tinkham's Introduction To Superconductivity 2nd Edition chapter 3 as reference. I've already proved that

$$\left \langle \left ( N - \overline{N} \right )^{2} \right \rangle = 4\sum_{k}u_{k}^{2}v_{k}^{2}$$

And also

$$\overline{N} = \sum_{k}2\left | v_{k}^{2} \right |$$

In page 51, Tinkham says, referring to my second equation: "This is nonzero unless the occupancy cuts off discontinuously. In fact, it will turn out that $v_{k}$ goes from 1 to 0, and $u_{k}$ goes from 0 to 1 in an energy range of $\sim kT_{c}$, so that the sum is $\sim (T_{c}/T_{F})\bar{N}$."
Then at page 59 there is a graph showing $1-v_{k}^{2}$ for $T=0$:
[image: Graph]
$$$$
From this graph I don't understand the statement I just quoted. Wouldn't the energy range to make those changes in $v_{k}$ and $u_{k}$ be $\sim 2kT_{c}$?
Going back to my initial problem, I guess I have to integrate my second equation over $\xi _{k}$ from $-kT_{c}$ to $kT_{c}$ to get to the approximation I want to prove. However, I don't seem to find a way to get there. I'm using $v_{k}$ and $u_{k}$ in their forms where they depend on the gap and on $\xi _{k}$ but I don't get anywhere near what I want (of course I have to introduce or take away Boltzmann's constant at some point but I don't think my problem is there).

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: But $kT\sim 2kT$....

Comment: Yeah I can see that, can you provide any help with the integration? Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that $u^2= (1+\tanh (\epsilon-\mu)/ 2kT_c)/2$ and $v^2=(1-\tanh (\epsilon-\mu)/2kT_c)/2$ (a resonable assumption given the curves in the figure and one that make s $|u^2|+|v|^2=1$) so that
$$
4u^2v^2= 1-\tanh^2 (\epsilon-\mu)/2kT_c= {\rm sech}^2\{(\epsilon-\mu)/ 2kT_c\}$$
and 
$$
4\sum_k u^2v^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty N(0)\, {\rm sech}^2\{(\epsilon-\mu)/ 2kT_c\} d\epsilon = 4 N(0)kT_c\approx 4N(0)\Delta(T=0) 
$$
Does this help?

Note $N(0)={\rm const.} \sqrt{\epsilon_f}$, $N = (2/3) (\hbox{ same const.})  \epsilon_f^{3/2}$ so $(N/\epsilon_f) \sim   N(0)$ making the integral  $N(\Delta/\epsilon_f)$ up to numerical constants.

Comment: It certainly did, thank you so much!

Comment: There are some errors in my formulae. Ill try and correct them. They are not important though.